# Are there any restrictions using substitutions in integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to evaluate the following definite integral:

$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}} dx$

Well I put the integral on symbolab to know its value ($4/3$)

However when I tried to calculate the integral using the substitution $x= t^2-1$ and making my new extremes of integration $1$ and $\sqrt 2$ I got to $\frac{4-2\sqrt 2}{3}$.

Well I wonder why... I verified on symbolab and the integral I calculated is correct. But the substitution gives my integral a different value.

Can someone explain me why? 
How can I make a correct substitution?

Thanks!

Comment: Substitute $\sqrt{x+1}=t$  $$\implies x=0, t=+1; x=1,t=+\sqrt{1+1}$

Comment: Substitutions defined by $C^1$-diffeomorphisms are valid. This is the case with your substitution as long as you pick a single side of the parabola. Not all substitutions are valid.

Comment: Example: $\int_{-1}^1 dx = 2$. Now make the substitution $x \mapsto x^2$ (in other words $t^2 = x$). We get $\int_{0}^1 2t dt = 1$. Note that $x \mapsto x^2$ traces $[0,1]$ twice as $x$ varies $[-1,1]$, so we do not have a bijection of integration regions.

Comment: @EricThoma Isn't the problem there that $f(x) = x^2$ has no solution $c$ to $f(c) = -1$, and so the substitution wouldn't make sense?

Comment: @GFauxPas You're right. This is a little cleaner since we don't use pullbacks. If we formulate the change of variables as $\int_{\varphi(U)} f(x) dx = \int_U f(\varphi(x)) \lvert J(x) \rvert dx$, with $J$ the Jacobian, then we should have a counterexample for $\varphi(x) = x^2$, $U = [-1,1]$, $f = 1$.

Comment: @GFauxPas But the problem of having multiple points in $\varphi(U)$ for each point in $U$ in analogous to having no point in $\varphi^{-1}(U)$ for a point in $U$, which is what my first example has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Symbolab's value is wrong. The integral is actually $\frac{4 - 2\sqrt{2}}{3},$ as you can check at [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%20x%20%2F%20sqrt(x%2B1)%20for%20x%3D0%20to%201)